# Collision detection with tiles

Tags: c#, xna

Alright, so I drew tiles on my map by the following code:

```
 for (int x = 0; x < WindowsWidth + TextureWidth; x += TextureWidth)
        {
            for (int y = 400; y < WindowsHeight; y += TextureHeight)
            {
                spriteBatch.Draw(Texture, new Rectangle((int)x, (int)y, TextureWidth, TextureHeight), Color.White);
            }
        }
```

I hope this code is good, if not, I'd like to hear your comments about it please.

Alright, so I don't know how can I make a rectangle collision detection with those tiles and my player.

Comment if you need another explanation for anything, thank you.

Comment: What have you tried? There are a ton of great resources on this subject from http://create.msdn.com/en-US/ to various books http://oreilly.com/catalog/0636920013709

Answer (score 5):

If you want simple rectangular collision detection, the Rectangle objects have a really nice method to help you with this ([Rectangle.Intersects](http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL0A865073DA96A7DA&feature=player_embedded&v=lk0GsyxCj-U)).  Take your tiles and intersect them with the rectangle of your character.  You'll want to optimize to not check EVERY tile in the map.  Since it sounds like you are new, you should check out Nick Gravelyn's Tile Engine Tutorials.  [The first part is here on YouTube](http://www.youtube.com/watch?list=PL0A865073DA96A7DA&feature=player_embedded&v=lk0GsyxCj-U).

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb464123.aspx

Comment: Keep in mind that if your player moves discretely between tiles (like, the player *is* a tile like a knight on a chessboard) then you want to do collision detection logically on some backing data structure, not with actual rectangle regions on screen.